# How to Create RSS Feed notification in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

iam a beginner level programmer in Android..Now iam developing an app for getting notification from a websites( for each new posts on that website)..How am doing this right now is,iam parsing RSS feeds from the website and saving it in database while opening that App ,After that displaying it .But now I need to set a notification for every new posts on this website.how i can do this?I know it is possible but how i can create RSS Feed Notification

Please ANy one help me

Comment: I assume its already answered here : http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/instant-notification-for-rss-feed

Comment: @user2328366 i mean i need notification in android